# About MAX30102, MLX90614 & Nodemcu-32s

Tags: nodemcu, temperature-sensor, breadboard

I am using Nodemcu-32s with MAX30102 & MLX90614.

I noticed a thing that when I was working with both sensor individually then both of them were working fine but when I started them using together by connecting them on breadboard then both of them were not working.

I checked by changing jumper wires & checking almost all holes of breadboard, then I came to know that both jumper wires & bread board are working fine.

After that, when I started using them individually again then I got "sensor not found" error.

I am not sure where I am making mistake.

I am connecting

| MAX30102 Pins | Nodemcu-32s Pins |
| --- | --- |
| Vin | 5V |
| SDA | G21 |
| SCL | G22 |
| GND | GND |

| MLX90614 Pins | Nodemcu-32s Pins |
| --- | --- |
| Vin | 5V |
| GND | GND |
| SDA | G21 |
| SCL | G22 |

I don't know if my sensors were burnt or not so how can I verify for the same? Apart from this I am not aware how can I get accurate Pulse Rate & SpO2

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". If your sensors worked before you put them on the same I²C bus at the same time, and they don't work individually now, chances are high that there is a wiring error or a damage. Are the sensors working, when you revert to your very first circuits? -- On your last statement: Please separate issues, ask a separate question for this. Probably this makes sense only after you have working sensors again.

Comment: what have you tried so far? On paper I mean.